# Mogodb Schema design : embedded or referenced

Tags: mongodb

I have a question about designing my application schema. My application handles objects, and status for these objects.
Object and status are quite small object, and in term of volume, it handles few millions of objects, each of these objects can have hundreds to ten of thousands status.

The main write operation of application is adding status (multiple times per day per object).
Read operations are various (list of object, object detail, many aggreagation framework queries to get stats about objects and status).

I try both approaches, it works pretty well for couple of hundred of obejcts with 1000-10000 status but can't figure out which is the more scalable.

Embedded objects :

```js
Objects:
[
    {
        "id": "0000000001",
        "name": "Resource 1",
        "description": "Resource 1",
        "owner": "John Doe",
        "created_at": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "status": [
            {
                "id": "0000000001",
                "position": [0, 0],
                "comment": "comment 1",
                "owner": "John Doe",
                "created_at": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": "0000000002",
                "position": [0, 0],
                "comment": "comment 2",
                "owner": "John Doe",
                "created_at": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Referenced objects :

```js
Objects:
[
    {
        "id": "0000000001",
        "name": "Resource 1",
        "description": "Resource 1",
        "owner": "John Doe",
        "created_at": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    }
]

Status
[
    {
        "id": "0000000001",
        "object_id": "0000000001",
        "position": [0, 0],
        "comment": "comment 1",
        "owner": "John Doe",
        "created_at": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "0000000002",
        "object_id": "0000000001",
        "position": [0, 0],
        "comment": "comment 2",
        "owner": "John Doe",
        "created_at": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

Best regards,

Mickael

Comment: Second approach is better in your case. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/#normalized-data-models ,  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#pattern

Comment: have you tried googled this? It was asked few weeks ago.

Comment: This is a bit too broad without a defined use case. But a fair point to mention is that if you are thinking of embedding arrays over 1000 items as you mention, then embedding may cause more performance problems than will be incurred by linking the data. Possibly go through the various cases in the link that was provided and maybe consider a "hybrid" solution, as is covered [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/)

Answer (score 0):

**Embedded** model is preferable If you want to get maximum performance and your single document is smaller then  [16 megabytes (maximum BSON document size)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size)

**Referenced** model in preferable when you need maximum scalability or some complex relationships.

So, if you sure that you can fit to the document size limit, you can use embedded model. But if you want guaranteed scalability - use referenced.

---

Here is some quotes from Mongo documentation:

> In general, use embedded data models when:
>
> - you have “contains” relationships between entities
> - you have one-to-many relationships between entities. In these    relationships the “many” or child documents always appear with or are 
>     viewed in the context of the “one” or parent documents.
>
> Reference to [Model One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#data-modeling-example-one-to-many)
>
> In general, embedding provides better performance for read operations,
>   as well as the ability to request and retrieve related data in a
>   single database operation. Embedded data models make it possible to
>   update related data in a single atomic write operation.
>
> In general, use normalized data models:
>
> - when embedding would result in duplication of data but would not provide sufficient read performance advantages to outweigh the
>     implications of the duplication.
> - to represent more complex many-to-many relationships.
> - to model large hierarchical data sets.
>
> References provides more flexibility than embedding. However,
>   client-side applications must issue follow-up queries to resolve the
>   references. In other words, normalized data models can require more
>   roundtrips to the server.
>
> Reference to [Model One-to-Many Relationships with Document References](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#data-modeling-publisher-and-books)